# Traveling distance for a flea flying from one dog's nose to another repeatedly until collision

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is:

Two dogs, each traveling 10 ft/sec, run toward each other from 500 feet apart. As they run, a flea flies from the nose of one dog to the nose of the other at 25 ft/sec. The flea flies between the dogs in this manner until it is crushed when the dogs collide. How far did the flea fly?

I know the dogs will collide after 25 seconds I used some cumbersome process to find the flea travels 610 ft. I've seen another solution indicate 25*25 = 625 ft (The rate of fly * the seconds before collison) which doesn't feel right to me.

What's the answer?

Comment: Can you write down your cumbersome process... both should give the same length. Providing the flea makes  Uturns instantaneously.

Comment: Why does $625$ ft. not sound right to you? Has the flea been continuously flying for $25$ seconds at the speed of $25$ ft/sec or not? Regardless of whether it was flying towards running dogs or stationery objects, if it did not fly distance equal to _speed $\times$ time duration_, there is something more to your question, that I do not understand.

Comment: It makes perfect sense this time round. I've been staring at this problem far to long. Feel silly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't linear algebra....

Regardless, this is a variation off the fameous "problem that foold Von Neuman."

The obvious solution is to treat this a geometric series and sum the series.

The "clever solution" is to say, the dogs will meet in 25 seconds.  The flea travels at 25 ft/sec for 25 sec = 625 ft.

When this question of was of Von Neuman, he answered almost immediately.  His interlocutor said, "you must have spotted the trick, most people try to sum the series."

Von Neuman responded that he did sum the series.

Summing the series is not that hard.
$(500)(\frac {25}{25+10})\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} (1-\frac {4}{7})^n\\
(500)(\frac {5}{7})(\frac {7}{4}) = 625$